# Not able to display date in view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, date, view

I had model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "txtDateOfBirthday")]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

And I need display in my view date, but it doesn't work.
My view look such:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new {@class = "form-control", @type = "date"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: In text box date doesn't display.

Comment: Are your sure the `DateOfBirth` isn't null?

Comment: Yes, in page source i have `<input value="05.02.2014" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of birth must be a date." id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="date">`

Comment: The problem is with the dots in your date. I think Razor is trying to find an object with "02.2014" property (properties). I've seen that before and drove me mad for half a day. Either change it to a static, plain old HTML `input` or play around with another date format (change to dash `-` to see that it's being displayed).

Comment: I change to @Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth",Model.DateOfBirth.HasValue?Model.DateOfBirth.Value.‌​ToString("dd-mm-yyyy"):"",new {@class = "form-control", @type = "date"}) but it also doesn't work.